# EF Queries Using Read Commited Though snapshot_isolation_state and is_read_committed_snapshot_on are ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, isolation-level, entity-framework, snapshot-isolation

I am running this query,

```
SELECT name
, snapshot_isolation_state
, is_read_committed_snapshot_on
FROM sys.databases s

name        snapshot_isolation_state    is_read_committed_snapshot_on
master        1                               0
tempdb        0                               0
model         0                               0
msdb          1                               0
MyDB1         1                               1
MyDB2         1                               1
```

MyDB1 and MyDB2 is enabled snapshot but still all my Entity Framework queries are using,

```
select transaction_isolation_level from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

All sessions values are `transaction_isolation_level=2` which means `Read Committed`. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `MyDB1` and `MyDB2` have `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`, queries using the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level will use row versioning instead of locking for read consistency. This behavior is similar to `SNAPSHOT` isolation level except at the statement level rather than transaction level. No action is needed on your part if this is your desired behavior.

One cannot determine from the `transaction_isolation_level` value reported by `sys.dm_exec_requests` whether a `READ COMMITTED` isolation level uses row versioning or locking.

The `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` database option is unrelated to `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` and may be toggled independently. `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` only needs to be set when you want to use the `SNAPSHOT` transaction isolation level with an explicit `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Now I am thinking to set `TransactionScope` with `IsolationLevel.Snapshot` as mentioned https://web.archive.org/web/20140325063216/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx
Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @user960567, it depends what you want to do. Using `TransactionScope` with `IsolationLevel.Snapshot` will start an explicit snapshot tranaction so all the queries executed within the transaction scope will reflect data at the time the transaction started.

Comment: Thanks. Dunno for whatever reason setting `IsolationLevel.Snapshot` started crashing the process(w3wp/IIS) which makes me thinking its risky. I have reverted back for.